# How can I declare an object with properties that I will be passing around inside of my function using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've been using the following:

```
var modal = {
    content: '',
    form: '',
    href: ''
}
```

But now I have started to use Typescript is there a better way I can declare an object and how can I declare the types of my properties. The reason I am using this object is that it's inside of a function and inside that function I have other functions that set and use the values of the properties. Is this the best way for me to do this or is there another way I could better do this with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
interface Modal {
    content: string;
    form: string;
    href: string;
}

function doIt() {

    var modal = {
        content: '',
        form: '',
        href: ''
    }

    function setStuff(m : Modal) {
        m.content = 'some content';
        m.form = 'form1';
        m.href = '...';
    }

    function clear(m : Modal) {
        m.content = m.form = m.href = '';
    }

    function dump(m : Modal) {
        console.log('content: '+ m.content);
        console.log('form: '+ m.form);
        console.log('href: '+ m.href);
    }

    dump(modal);
    setStuff(modal);
    dump(modal);
    clear(modal);
    dump(modal);
}
```

Notice you don't need to declare the variable `modal` to be of type `Modal`, TypeScript will infer this information automatically. Just adding the type to the functions is sufficient.

But if you like you could also make this type information explicit for the variable:

```
var modal : Modal = {
    content: '',
    form: '',
    href: ''
}
```